# Overriding a Generic class function binding for using in callbacks

Tags: c++, oop, overriding, virtual

I have a program which creates rough types to be overridden by other library.
For instance a Base class called ScriptEng which is overridden by a library for script implementations; For example Lua.

So this library creates a type called LuaScriptEng from ScriptEng.

During runtime the libray is called in and a pointer to this type is created.

```
ScriptEng* script = LoadClassFromLibrary("LuaScriptEng.dll","LuaScriptEng");
```

Or

```
ScriptEng* script = LoadClassFromLibrary("SqurrelScript.dll","SqurrelScriptEng");
```

The problem occurs when I try to pass Other class methods to this instance for exposure to this embedded lang.

```
Game* game = new Game(); //contains stuff.
auto game_bind = script->createClass<Game>("Game", game);
game_bind->bindMethod("helo", &Game::hello);
```

This works all well and good up until i have to override the class methods in the LuaScriptEng class.

```
class ScriptEng
{
public:
    ScriptEng();
    template<class T>
    ScriptClass<T>* createClass(const std::string& name,T* cla)
    {
        //Implement per engine information here in children
        return new ScriptClass<T>(cla);
    }
    virtual bool callFunction(const std::string& name)
    {
        return true;
    }
    virtual ~ScriptEng();
};
```

Since it is impossible in this sense to have a "virtual" template function.

I cant thing of a good work around for this, unless of course I create dozens of static functions and instead of binding the class in pieces I use them instead.

I'm trying to expose functions to the scripting lang as easier to understand calling types like

```
Game.somefunction(); //From lua or some other lang, call the current instance of this function.
```

Now the idea of a workaround that I have would probably work, but its really messy.

From what I read wrapping generics in this case would be "Type erasure" But in doing so i'm looking at somewhere in the neighborhood of 5-9 function calls per single script call which REALLY would bog down the program.

What is a better way to do this other then that?

Comment: There's a lot missing here but if I understand, you want to derive `ScriptEng` and override `createClass`? If that's the case it depends on your needs. If a given `ScriptEng` object will always be used to create one type, you could template the base class instead of templating the base member [example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ysZ6InzAncnAZY3v).

Comment: you subset of `T` is limited, would it make sense to have `virtual createGameClass(const std::string&, Game*)` and so on instead of your template ?

Comment: No, cause there will be multiple classes that I am exposing using this.